# Is there a tool that will allow me to design a SQL Database, then script it for me?

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server-2008, database-design, database-schema

I am looking for a tool that will allow me to design my SQL 2008 database, including the tables, columns, relationships between tables (PK,FK etc) and then produce scripts for me that I can run to create the database.

The idea here is that rather than plan it once, then manually script, I can get a good overview of how my database will look, then get the tool to script it for me.

Then I can make any changes I need and just re-script.

Does such a tool exist? Anything built in to Visual Studio 2010 (Ultimate)?

Comment: MS Visio will generate SQL for you based on a DDL diagram

Comment: Yes.  It's called a database consultant.  :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not kill two birds with one stone? Define and access your database with NHibernate(insert other ORM here) and generate create/alter scripts with SchemaExport (or other ORM's tool). Do you really want some random Microsoft wizard to create your tables?

Answer (score 2):

I know you can do this in SQL Server Management Studio.  It will allow you to create DBs, the tables inside of them, along with their fields.  It also has interfaces to make FK and PK relationships.  It does much more then that as well.  It allows you to easily change the configurations of tables, auto increment of ID's, etc.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the Entity Framework designer mentioned above, you can also use a Database Project in Visual Studio or you can use SQL Server Management Studio itself.  You'll have to do per-object script creation in SSMS, whereas VS Database project will compile into the creation and/or update scripts.  The fact that it integrates with version control is another huge win if this is a project of any size.
Database Projects: http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/07/29/visual-studio-2010-database-projects.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Almost any SQL database tool can let you create your database design.

After you've done it, almost all database tools will allow you to export your database to an **.sql** file. Then you can use that file to initiate the database.

Answer (score 1):

In VS2010, you should have a project type "SQL Server 2008 Database Project" which will let you design and then script your database.  Benefits of the project include being able to put the project into source control, and an install generation which will set up a new database or modify an existing one to match the schema in the installer.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework designer can do this for you

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456817.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of, but I mean, you could always write a program to generate some SQL for you.  I actually did this at my job.  I wrote up a program that will read in an Excel spreadsheet and determine what the fields are.  It then allows you to format each field with things such as a primary or foriegn key, not null, auto increment etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working on a c# solution, you can use the Entity Framework designer in a Model-first approach.  I'm not a fan of it but it will do what you're asking for.

Another approach would be to use SQL Management Studio's database diagramming.  This will automatically generate scripts and create your database as you edit the diagram.  When you're done you can use Tools -> Generate Scripts to see the final SQL script.

Answer (score 0):

I typically use Microsoft Visio Enterprise Architect to do this for me. Visio provides a great interface for design and when you're finished you can generate the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Sybase Powerdesigner is one of the most powerfull tool:

http://www.sybase.com/products/modelingdevelopment/powerdesigner

But,its main disadvantage is the price.....